Coming to China with a bit of a cough
I'm going to China for the first time and I am coming from the USA sphere of influence so obviously I am quite scared of what may happen there.
I developed a bit of a cough (seasonal autumn thing, most of my coworkers sneeze or cough at this time of the year) and my question is: How tough is the health control at the airport (Beijing if it's relevant)? Will I be put in a quarantine if I cough once at the passport control?
How seriously are they taking temperature control? (I am not running any fever, but I may get tired sooner with all the luggage, and show 37 C instead of 36.6 C)
My apologies if the post sounds panicky, it's the fear of the unknown. I have already read plenty of posts on phones and tablets and the comments suggest I shouldn't be worried, it's not different than anywhere else, but is it?

Do you believe it's just a cough or have you got tested on COVID?

Thank you, that's a valid point. I got myself tested just to make sure.

Are they still testing for covid at the airports in China?

@grisha No and now it's actually extremely difficult to get tested in China!

Thank you all for your comments and answers. It's a pity I can pick only one. They all helped me. To share my own experience - the airport security and health checks were very similar to what you see at any other airport (Australia, Europe, USA). There was a temperature check (just a camera) - hardly noticeable and nobody was selected. There was a form, asking if you are healthy and what countries you had been to in the last 2 years. Again, it's not statistical evidence, but from what I could see - the procedures went relatively smoothly for everyone and there were no extraordinary hassles.

At Beijing Capital Airport this summer, they had a health checkpoint that you just walked through. I guess if you are very visibly unhealthy or your body temperature is above a certain threshold, they might pull you out.

"I guess" isn't really an answer, is it?

I was totally healthy every time I entered China so far, so I can't know what happens if you are visibly unwell or when some IR camera says your face is too warm. I can say that they do not give you these paper cards anymore where you can self-report your STDs.

It may not be a perfect answer, but it helps me anyway. I realize that the final decision will be taken by an official at the airport, but the individual experiences give me an overall picture

No, there are no checks at all. I'm not 100% sure because I use the electronic (nationals') gates, but at most points of entry the health inspection stands aren't even staffed (or staffed by just one token inspector), and the IR thermometers are quite apparently not even turned on. Unless you look like you might have TB or MERS or some serious stuff, no one would even bat an eye. If you have a mild cough people will just think you have a cold. If you are really sick that immigration would care, you probably wouldn't be boarded in the first place.
P.S.: The other answers/comments mentioned AIDS/STD declarations, but there have not been any entry barriers on AIDS/STD positive people since 2010 anyways.


Inspection & Quarantine：

Incoming passengers having diseases such as fever, vomit, jaundice, diarrhea, acute rash, lymphadenopathy, AIDS, venereal disease, mental disorder or open tuberculosis should initiatively report to the inspection and quarantine officials;


https://en.bcia.com.cn/lkzndd.html
So if you are having cough but no fever I think it is safe. But if you want to be sure just report yourself to health inspector at the quarantine station.

Unless you actually have a serious infectious disease and want to be quarantined or something, self-reporting yourself to the health inspector seems unadvisable.
